# Who is earning the Safe Paymaster fees?

Tags: gnosis-safe, fees, safe, paymaster

I am running a wallet project where the business model is to earn revenue by Paymaster fees in ERC20 tokens.

Will Safe allow me to set my own Paymaster fees and will Safe allow me to earn revenue that way? Or is Safe controlling the Paymaster and I am only allowed to use it on Safe's terms meaning Safe will keep the revenue?

Comment: Safe doesn't have a paymaster. The technical implementation and a fee structure is up to you.